# how to lock test cases from editing in azure devOps until tester tested and approved

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Once test case or test plan is assigned to tester then test case should not edited until it is tested and approved. How can we restrict test cases from being edited once test case assigned to tester?

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict test cases from being edited by managing the **access-level permissions** like below:

> **Please note that area path permissions let you grant or restrict access to `edit or modify test plans` or test suites assigned to those areas. You can restrict access to users or groups.**

In order to set those permissions,
***Go to Azure DevOps -> Your Project -> Project Settings -> Project Configuration -> Areas***

[image]

Choose the **...** context menu and select **Security** like below:

[image]

Now, choose the users or group you want to manage access and set the permissions for  **Edit work items in this node** **Manage test plans**  and  **Manage test suites**  to  **`Deny`**.

[image]

For more information in detail, please **refer** below links.

**References:**

[Sample custom rule scenarios - Azure DevOps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/rule-samples?view=azure-devops&tabs=inheritance#restrict-modification-of-work-items-by-a-group)

[Set permissions for work tracking - Azure DevOps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops)

[Set permissions and access for manual testing - Azure DevOps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-test?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#grant-access-to-manual-testing-features)